# YouTube API: How to obtain text of Related videos, given a video's URL?

Tags: java, youtube

I have a pretty straight forward task -

> Given the URL of a video, I want to extract information of its Related videos (and by information I mean their Title, Tags, Description). 
>   I use Java version of the YouTube API and couldn't find out how to do that quickly. Also, this site: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java provides some information. The code they provide is:

```
if (videoEntry.getRelatedVideosLink() != null) {
  String feedUrl = videoEntry.getRelatedVideosLink().getHref();

  VideoFeed videoFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(feedUrl), VideoFeed.class);
  printVideoFeed(videoFeed, true);
}
```

I don't know how to create a videoEntry given only the URL..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
        class YouTubeVideoInfo {
                private String channel;
                private String url;
                private long views;
                private int comments;
                private int ratings;
                private int likes;
                private int dislikes;
                private String thumbnail;
                private String title;
                .....
        }

        public static final String YOUTUBE_GDATA_SERVER = "http://gdata.youtube.com";
        public static final String USER_FEED_PREFIX = YOUTUBE_GDATA_SERVER + "/feeds/api/users/";
        public static final String UPLOADS_FEED_SUFFIX = "/uploads";
    ...............
        public YouTubeVideoInfo getVideoInfo(YouTubeService service, String channel, String url) {
VideoFeed videoFeed = service.getFeed(
        new URL(USER_FEED_PREFIX + channel + UPLOADS_FEED_SUFFIX), VideoFeed.class);
List<VideoEntry> videoEntries = videoFeed.getEntries();
for (VideoEntry videoEntry : videoEntries) {

    YouTubeMediaGroup mediaGroup = videoEntry.getMediaGroup();
    if (mediaGroup != null && mediaGroup.getPlayer() != null && videoEntry.getTitle() != null) {

        if (url.equals(mediaGroup.getPlayer().getUrl())) {
            String title = videoEntry.getTitle().getPlainText();

            MediaKeywords keywords = mediaGroup.getKeywords();

            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaGroup.getPlayer();


            final YtStatistics statistics = videoEntry.getStatistics();

            final YouTubeVideoInfo videoInfo = new YouTubeVideoInfo(channel,
                    mediaPlayer.getUrl(), statistics != null
                    ? statistics.getViewCount() : 0);

            if (videoEntry.getComments() != null
                    && videoEntry.getComments().getFeedLink() != null)
                videoInfo.comments =
                        videoEntry.getComments().getFeedLink().getCountHint();

            final Rating rating = videoEntry.getRating();
            if (rating != null)
                videoInfo.ratings = rating.getNumRaters();

            final YtRating ytRating = videoEntry.getYtRating();

            if (ytRating != null) {
                videoInfo.likes = ytRating.getNumLikes();
                videoInfo.dislikes = ytRating.getNumDislikes();
            }


            final List<MediaThumbnail> thumbnails = mediaGroup.getThumbnails();
            if (!thumbnails.isEmpty())
                videoInfo.thumbnail = thumbnails.get(thumbnails.size() / 2).getUrl();

            if (videoEntry.getTitle() != null)
                videoInfo.title = videoEntry.getTitle().getPlainText();

            return videoInfo;
        }
    }
    .... // exception handling
```

Comment: Thanks for replying!
I'm fairly new to Java and so am not able to figure out which part of your code to use as is, and which to edit. Some help would be very appreciated..

Comment: For the first class add setters/getters (usually IDE generates them). Add constants to another class where the method is. Just add exception handling or declare method throwing them. This is pretty much whole code, doesn't require a lot of work in order to use. 

I believe you already found out how to get instance of YouTubeService authenticated in YouTube, right?

Comment: I don't think I need authentication because I am not performing any write, update or delete action. Am I correct? And on the other (Java) part, let me try some more and I'll get back if I still cannot figure out how to make it work. Thanks again! :)

Comment: I'm not sure. You have to check. When I implemented the code above, it was required. Maybe something has changed.

Comment: I am not sure if I can use the code that you have provided for my task.. I think I have a key issue that is still unresolved. I have the URL of a YouTube video, and I don't know a way to create a corresponding VideoEntry. I believe once I can get my hands on the corresponding VideoEntry (ie VideoEntry of the video corresponding to the URL), I can get information about its Related videos (I know how to get RV from VideoEntry), but getting VideoEntry is where I am stuck.

Comment: The method I provided takes a video entry by URL of a video in a channel. You have to know the channel from where video is.

Comment: Yes, all I have is the URL.. I do not have information wrt channel.

Comment: You can open a page and parse channel name from it, if you don't find any API.

Comment: I see.. Can you please given an example? Let's say URL=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3q3JkNUPmI . What would the channel be for this example? I can then create a parsing script based on the webpage's HTML. thanks for your help!

Comment: The channel for the video is DonZordon.
Use Jsoup to parse a page (it supports CSS selectors).

Comment: I see.. will try with this. Thanks for your help :) Have a great day ahead!

Answer (score 0):

I have got a method to do what I intended to. I did not require name of the Channel (username that uploaded the video). All I need is a URL. YouTube has an ID corresponding to each video. For example, for the video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3q3JkNUPmI ,  the ID is "f3q3JkNUPmI" (without the quotes). So, all you need to do is to create a String containing the feed link that you want to get. This can be created as:

> String Video_Related_Feed="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/f3q3JkNUPmI/related?v=2" (don't replace https with http -- it does not work)
>   Obviously, one can automate this .. I'm just giving the hard-coded example. 
>   Now get the actual Feed based on this address:
>
> VideoFeed videoFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(Video_Related_Feed), VideoFeed.class);
>   This feed contains VideoEntry of the Related videos (corresponding to our original URL), each of which can be accessed by a for loop:
>   for (VideoEntry ve : videoFeed.getEntries()) { insert your code here }
>
> References: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference
>   andhttps://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java
>   (sorry, I had to write last link like that because I couldn't post more than 2 URLs).
>
> I hope this helps someone.